# Normal Force on an object hanging over a cliff

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, torque

this is the problem I'm having:

Imagine I have an object with mass m, also with equal distribution of the mass. This object is portruding over a cliff, with some fraction of it being suspended over the cliff. I want to calculate the angular acceleration it will have while falling off. For this, I need the torque and its moment of inertia. The moment of inertia can be calculated using integration since I know where the axis is (the fraction of it over the cliff). For the torque, I need to know all forces that are acting on it - the weight should just be acting on the center of mass, but I have no idea neither what magnitude the normal force of the cliff has nor where exactly it is acting. It would be great if someone could help me out, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the object to fall off, its center of gravity has to be over the cliff.

Under such condition, the reaction force would be concentrated at the edge, which serves as an axis of rotation, and therefore this force would have no contribution to the torque.

Comment: Thanks heaps. Is there some kind of intuition/reason as to why the reaction force applies to the edge?

Comment: @Dovahkiin You can check out [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/420576/force-diagram-on-an-overhanging-book/420649#420649), which explains how and why the normal force moves toward the edge.

Comment: You are talking about right before it falls, right?

Comment: @Yes, right before it falls and while it is rotating over the edge.